# Posting JSON body to Flask app, throws '500 - Internal Server Error'

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, flask

I'm hosting my Flask app on App Engine Flex. I'm trying to POST a request to my app which contains some JSON. I get a '500 Internal Server Error' when I try to do this.

```
@app.route('/input', methods=['POST','GET'])
def input():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        kpi = request.json['kpi']
        hanaview = request.json['source']
        first_property = request.json['startnode']['first_property']
        first_value = request.json['startnode']['first_value']
        filters = request.json['filters']
        filters['CalMonth'] = tuple(filters['CalMonth'])
        progression = request.json['progression']
        alert_tree = get(kpi, hanaview, filters, progression, first_property, first_value, compare=lambda x: x < 10 and x > -10)
        tree = alert_tree.get_tree()
        return jsonify(tree)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return "this is a GET request"
```

I can this without any problem locally, could someone tell me why is this happening?

JSON:

```
{
    "kpi": "MarketSharePercentCD",
    "source": "MarketShareFSet",
    "startnode": {
        "first_property": "Division",
        "first_value": "GE"
    },
    "filters": {
        "CalYear" :  2019,
        "CalMonth" : [4,5],
        "ManufacturerDescription": "test"
    },
    "progression": [
        "CategoryDescription"
    ]
}
```

Error message:

```
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='URL', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: URL (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f5039cb0a50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
```

Comment: You should be getting the full stacktrace in the server log/output. The error will be explained there

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [26/Aug/2019 13:36:43] "POST /input HTTP/1.1" 200 - that's all I get in the logs

Comment: That's not the same request. The `200` in the end is the status code. 200 != 500

Comment: 505 means "HTTP Version Not Supported", I doubt its even reaching your flask application, it may get rejected by an intermediate component (the web server for instance). If you don't have anything in your logs, maybe check the response header to see if you can find additional information on the issuer

Comment: Sorry my bad, its 500 not 505

Comment: I have added the full stack trace log from GCP